# Stop stream.filter() on button click

Tags: python, flask, tweepy

I am using tweepy to stream tweets and store it in a file. I am using python and flask. On a click of a button the stream start to fetch the tweets. What I want is, on a click of a button the stream should get stopped.
I know the answers related to a counter variable, but I don't want specific number of tweets to fetch.

Thanks in advance

```
def fetch_tweet():
    page_type = "got"



    lang_list = request.form.getlist('lang') 

    print lang_list
    #return render_template("index.html",lang_list=lang_list,page_type=page_type)
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    with open('hashtags.txt') as hf:
        hashtag = [line.strip() for line in hf]
        print hashtag

    print request.form.getlist('fetchbtn')
    if (request.form.getlist('stopbtn')) == ['stop']:
        print "inside stop"
        stream.disconnect()
        return render_template("analyse.html")
    elif (request.form.getlist('fetchbtn')) == ['fetch']:
        stream.filter(track=lang_list, async=True)
        return render_template("fetching.html")
```

Answer (score 3):

So I'm assuming your initial button links to the initializing of a tweepy stream (i.e. a call to `stream.filter()`).

If you're going to allow your application to run while tweet collection is happening, you'll need to collect tweets **asynchronously** (threaded). Otherwise once you call `stream.filter()` it will lock your program up while it collects tweets until it either reaches some condition you have provided it or you ctrl-c out, etc.

To take advantage of tweepy's built in threading, you simply need to add the `async` parameter to your stream initialization, like so:

```
stream.filter(track=['your_terms'], async=True)
```

This will thread your tweet collection and allow your application to continue to run.

Finally, to stop your tweet collection, link a flask call to a function that calls `disconnect()` on your `stream` object, like so:

```
stream.disconnect()
```

This will disconnect your stream and stop tweet collection. [Here](https://github.com/dbernard/Pyckaxe/blob/master/pyckaxe.py) is an example of this exact approach in a more object oriented design (see the `gather()` and `stop()` methods in the `Pyckaxe` object).

---

**EDIT -** Ok, I can see your issue now, but I'm going to leave my original answer up for others who might find this. You issue is where you are creating your `stream` object.

Every time `fetch_tweet()` gets called via flask, you are creating a new `stream` object, so when you call it the first time to start your stream it creates an initial object, but the second time it calls `disconnect()` on a **different** stream object. Creating a single instance of your stream will solve the issue:

```
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)

def fetch_tweet():
    with open('hashtags.txt') as hf:
        hashtag = [line.strip() for line in hf]
        print hashtag

    print request.form.getlist('fetchbtn')
    if (request.form.getlist('stopbtn')) == ['stop']:
        print "inside stop"
        stream.disconnect()
        return render_template("analyse.html")
    elif (request.form.getlist('fetchbtn')) == ['fetch']:
        stream.filter(track=lang_list, async=True)
        return render_template("fetching.html")
```

Long story short, you need to create your `stream` object **outside** of `fetch_tweets()`. Good luck!

Comment: See my answer please I have shared the piece of code

Comment: When you say it "still has no effect", what do you mean exactly? What is failing to happen? Can you edit your question to include the entire function?

Comment: I have added the piece of code. "still has no effect" means that the stream is still fetching the tweets and do not stop.

Comment: Sorry, if you looked already, check it again. I tailored the answer more for Flask/functions.

Comment: Thanx bro, the problem was with the scope of stream object. Your solution worked for me. Thanx again

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer when you get a chance, I'd really appreciate it.